# Gdx.files.internal not using android assets path

Tags: libgdx

Whenever I try to use Gdx.files.internal to get a FileHandle, I am getting a FileNotFoundException like follows:

```
    <PATH TO MY GAME>\desktop\xml\screen.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I set my project up using the libgdx project setup tool, and it seems that my asset folder within my desktop project is the same as my android project (they're linked). However, when I go to my desktop project there is a bin folder with my assets. If I change the path to "/bin/..." then I can run the project without any exceptions. However, I feel this may be a problem if I export as a JAR.

Code:

```
    final FileHandle screenXML = Gdx.files.internal("xml/screen.xml");
```

[image: files]

Comment: You have to put everything in the assets folder in the android project. You will use gradle to package your jar files and it will put everything in the right place.

Comment: I have added an image to show that my assets folders are linked (i.e. I have everything in my android project's asset folder).

Comment: same problem here, I would love to find the answer. It only happened after I updates to the latest nightlies (last week)

Comment: I added my answer. It may be too local to my problem, but try making sure you're not using the ".file()" function, and if so use the .read() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem stemmed from the following (credit goes to the awesome and patient IRC community members for Libgdx):

```
    // final Document screenDoc = docBuilder.parse(screenXML.file());
    // Note: MUST use .read() here, not .file(), as we link from the android assets!
    final Document screenDoc = docBuilder.parse(screenXML.read());
```